# Issue with MySQLDB 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x92

Tags: python-3.x, mysql-python

I have an issue running a query using MySQLdb. I have the following error message

```
': 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x92 in position 2: invalid start byte
```

I have been able to run this query in the past without issue of encoding and therefore I don't get where my issue comes from. 
The only change I have done is downloading Postgres on my laptop and removing (accidentally) a db.sqlite3 file. But I don't understand why this will impact the encoding of my query especially since I don't have any special characters. Running a more simple query works fine and running this query from my colleague laptop also works.

The query is as following:

```
SLEEPERS_QUERY = """
select * from candidates"""
```

```
import MySQLdb as db


with SSHTunnelForwarder(
    ssh_address_or_host = host,
    ssh_port = 22,
    ssh_username = ssh_username,
    ssh_pkey = ssh_private_key,
    remote_bind_address = (rds, 3306), # 3306 = mysql port
) as server:
    server.start()
    print('Connected to the SSH server')

    while True:
        try:
            conn = db.connect(
                host = localhost,
                port = server.local_bind_port,
                user = user,
                passwd = password,
                db = database
            )
            print('Connected to the database server')
            break

        except: pass
    df = pd.read_sql_query(query,conn)

return df
```

Comment: According to http://www.alanwood.net/demos/ansi.html, 0x92 is a "smart" right single quotation mark which is used only by Windows -- the character does not exist in unicode, so it can't be decoded by the utf-8 codec... but we don't see that character in your example (??), which is strange.  Maybe your file was edited by a Windows machine?

Comment: Hey @Everett, thank you for your answer. Yes indeed we are two working on this and my colleague is under linux (but not windows).

Comment: And furthermore there is no single quote in my code. I am very confused

Comment: It is indeed strange...  sometimes I've been bitten when I've copied + pasted queries (especially from the web or from message clients) and sometimes I've had to resort to literally re-typing a query to ensure that no weird characters (e.g. hidden characters) ended up in my input.  Hopefully someone has a better suggestion, but it might be worth a try (?).

Comment: I tried this but doesn't fix it. It seems it's an issue from my environment but I still didn't solve it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found a solution: my default encoding changed to from latin1 to utf8.

I had to add `charset = 'latin1'`

```
conn = db.connect(
            host = localhost,
            port = server.local_bind_port,
            user = user,
            passwd = password,
            db = database,
            charset = 'latin1'
            )
```